# JMeter doesnt pass http post request sampler body data as json

Tags: json, apache, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am using JMeter and i am currently facing this issue.

I want to perform a POST request to an API function but somehow when it gets sent to the call, my body data doesnt send in JSON format.

This is the body data sent

```
{
    "project_id": "2",
    "name": "Jaya Jadon",
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "remarks": "",
    "co_applicants":[
        {
            "name": "Wongg Feig Uncle",
            "phone": "0123476798",
            "email": "unclee@weie.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Wineg Feie Father",
            "phone": "0123496897",
            "email": "fatheer@weie.com"
        }
    ],
    "documents": [
        {
            "booking_form": "",
            "consent_form": [   
                "https://www.jjj.com/CF1.jpg"
            ],
            "ic_passport_no":[
                "https://www.jjj.com/IC1.jpg"
            ],
            "additional": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

But this is what gets sent to when the POST request is sent

```
{
    "{\r\n\t\"project_id\"" => ">\"2\",\r\n\t\"name\"=>\"Jaya Jadon\",\r\n\t\"phone\"=>\"0123456789\",\r\n\t\"email\": \"email@email.com\",\r\n\t\"remarks\": \"\",\r\n\t\"co_applicants\":[\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"name\": \"Wongg Feig Uncle\",\r\n\t\t\t\"phone\": \"0123476798\",\r\n\t\t\t\"email\": \"unclee@weie.com\"\r\n\t\t},\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"name\": \"Wineg Feie Father\",\r\n\t\t\t\"phone\": \"0123496897\",\r\n\t\t\t\"email\": \"fatheer@weie.com\"\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t],\r\n\t\"documents\": [\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"booking_form\": \"\",\r\n\t\t\t\"consent_form\": [\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\"https://www.jjj.com/CF1.jpg\"\r\n\t\t\t],\r\n\t\t\t\"ic_passport_no\":[\r\n\t\t\t\t\"https://www.jjj.com/IC1.jpg\"\r\n\t\t\t],\r\n\t\t\t\"additional\": \"\"\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t]\r\n}",
                   "format" => "json",
               "controller" => "v1/lp_developer_referrals",
                   "action" => "create"
}
```

And this is what I am expecting to get

```
{
       "project_id" => "2",
             "name" => "Jaya Jadon",
            "phone" => "0123456789",
            "email" => "email@email.com",
          "remarks" => nil,
    "co_applicants" => nil,
        "documents" => [
        [0] {
              "booking_form" => nil,
              "consent_form" => [
                [0] "https://www.jjj.com/CF1.jpg"
            ],
            "ic_passport_no" => [
                [0] "https://www.jjj.com/IC1.jpg"
            ],
                "additional" => nil
        }
    ],
           "format" => "json",
       "controller" => "v1/lp_developer_referrals",
           "action" => "create"
}
```

Can someone explain to me why my Jmeter is not taking my body data as json objects?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter should send data "as is", double check the following configuration:

1. Make sure `Use multipart/form-data for HTTP POST` box is **not checked** in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or in the [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))
2. Make sure you have [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) configured to send [`Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

More information: [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to add a "HTTP Header Manager" with a "Content-Type" with a value "application/json" before your requests, or inside them. Tell us if the behavior is correct.